# $M_{n+1}=\{\frac{1}{2}(a+b):a,b\in M_n\}\cup\{\frac {1}{2}ab:a,b\in M_n\}, n\in\mathbb {N_0}$. Find bounds of ${M_n}$ independent from $n$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I am preparing for my analysis exam by trying to solve old exam tasks from my professor, since he often uses his tasks from his earlier exams. I need help with this task:

Let $M_0=\{1,2\}$ and $$M_{n+1}=\left\{\frac{1}{2}(a+b):a,b\in M_n\right\}\cup\left\{\frac {1}{2}ab:a,b\in M_n\right\}, n\in\mathbb {N_0}$$ with $n\in\mathbb {N_0}$ (all natural numbers + 0).

a) Determine the  from $n \in$ $\mathbb{N_0}$ independent upper and lower bounds for $M_n$.

My idea is to start the task by showing $M_1$ and $M_2$. By inserting the elements of $M_0$ and $M_1$ in $M_{n+1}$ we get for:

- $M_1=\{1,\frac{3}{2},2\}\cup\{\frac{1}{2},1,2\}$
- $M_2=\{\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4},2\}\cup\{\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{8},1,\frac{3}{2},\frac {9}{4},2\}$. I can't guarantee that I missed some elements, but nevertheless we can see that $x\leq 2$ and $x\geq 0$ $\forall x\in M_n$. So regardless which n we choose, the upper bounds are all $\geq 2$ and the lower bounds are $\leq 0$. But how do we show that more mathematical. These two examples wouldn't be sufficient to proof that.

b) Show with help of mathematical induction, that $1 \in M_n$ and $(\frac{1}{2})^n\in M_n$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N_0}$.

$1 \in M_n$: P(0) is true, since $1\in M_0$. We proof P(n+1) under the term that P(n): $1 \in M_n$ is true. Thus we can choose a=b=1 and then $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(a+b)=1$. Since $1 \in M_{n+1}\implies 1\in M_n$

$(\frac{1}{2})^n\in M_n$: P(0) is true, $(\frac{1}{2})^0=1\in M_0$. We proof P(n+1) under the term that P(n): $(\frac{1}{2})^n \in M_n$ is true. Thus we can choose $a=b=(\frac{1}{2})^n$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot (ab)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{2n}=(\frac{1}{2})^{2n+1} \in M_{n+1}.$$
But how do we get $(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}$ $\in M_{n+1}$.

c) Determine the supremum and infimum of $M=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} M_n$. Are these maximum and minimum of $M$?

Well in a) we already discovered the lower ($\leq 0$) and upper bounds ($\geq 2$), which are independent from $n$. Thus these are the lower and upper bounds of $M$. So $2$ is our supremum and $0$ is our infimum. Since $2 \in M$, the supremum of $M$ is maximum of $M$. Since $0 \notin M$, the infimum $0$ is not a minimum of $M$. I know the solution is pretty obvious. But like in a), I want the proof to be more mathematical, since I don't belive that this kind of proof would give any points. Any advice?

Comment: Your proof of b) is incorrect. If you are using induction you need to prove that $(\tfrac{1}{2})^{\color{red}{ n+1}} \in M_{n+1}$

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Well Thats why it was too easy. But how do I get the result that $(\frac {1}{n})^{n+1}$ $\in M_{n+1}$. Any advice?

Comment: Well, you used $\frac12(a+b)$ a lot, but that can never make you smaller numbers than what you start with. What about $\frac12ab$?

Comment: We get $(\frac {1}{2})^{2n+1}$....

Comment: Just take $a=1$, $b=(\tfrac{1}{2})^n$.

Comment: @jjagmath Oh my god. Thank you so much. I was thinking about using 1 too, but I just did not try this simple way. Thanks a lot. Do you also have an advice for a) or c)?